# Rails plugin/gem for printing ID cards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to be able to print ID cards out of a rails club membership app I am creating.
Is there anything available that does something like this? 
If there is no such thing available, does anyone have any general suggestions on how to implement card printing from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that printing an ID card would be no different than printing any other page in a web app. So can you just create a view that looks like what you want out of your ID card and then either:

1. Use a special "Print Version" link that opens the ID template with no layout, which you can simply print, or
2. Use CSS media queries to only print the ID card's container element, or
3. Just print the whole layout and cut the ID card out of the middle of it.

Or was there a more specific need you had?

Comment: Option #2 is a good idea I hadn't thought of. I'll have to look more into that.The card printers only print on the standard credit card size of plastic cards so #3 wouldn't work.